Upgrade from 4 to 5 error
When running the php craft up command as one of the last steps for the upgrade I get the following error.
*** applying m230511_215903_content_refactor
Exception: A field layout element has a duplicate UUID. Reinstall Craft CMS ^4.4.14 and run `utils/fix-field-layout-uids` before upgrading to Craft CMS 5.

When I go back to version 4 and run the suggested command I get the following message.
Done. No duplicate UUIDs were found.
It seems like I am stuck and unable to upgrade.
Did anyone else encounter this issue?

This was a bug in Craft CMS 5 and was fixed in release 5.0.3.
